# How to create a simple code from custom created SVG which can be placed on other websites

Tags: javascript, html, svg, hyperlink, badge

After creating a custom SVG with shapes and text, the big code is left:

```
    <a href="..." target="_blank">
      <svg id="svg-1" width="120px" height="120px" version="1.1" ...>
        50 lines of code...
      </svg>
    </a>
```

How could one create a simple code which can someone copy and paste on a website? Is it possible?

I have tried to compress the svg and the code is still huge.
Also, I have tried to convert the svg into png and the code was even longer by doing that.

Comment: It sounds as though your SVG itself is longer than you'd like. I expect it can be shortened so why not paste it into your question so we can advise? Other than that, 50 lines is not really what I would call 'huge', so perhaps I'm not understanding why you'd like people to cut and paste it. Usually I'd be concerned about file size and code clarity rather than length.

Comment: You may put the 50 lines of code inside a `<g>` element with an `id` and this `<g>` inside a `<defs>` element.  Put the `#svg-1` at the top of the body and let it be `width="0" height="0"`  Then when you need the svg image you create another svg element and inside this svg you `<use>` the `<g>` element, To do this you need only one line of code.